# Set Pivot for Rotate animation (ObjectAnimator) , not working?

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I've applied a Rotate animation to a button using ObjectAnimator, while the rotation seems to work; the pivot point still remains the top left corner of the button.

**MainActivity**

```
Button bt1;

float pivotX=0f;
float pivotY=0f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    pivotX = bt1.getX() + (float)bt1.getWidth();// 500;// bt1.getHeight() ;
    pivotY = bt1.getY() + (float)bt1.getHeight();// 500;// bt1.getWidth(); 

    bt1.setPivotX(pivotX);
    bt1.setPivotY(pivotY);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void rotate()
{
    ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bt1, View.ROTATION_X,360);
    rotate.setDuration(2000);

    AnimatorSet aSet = new AnimatorSet();
    aSet.play(rotate);
    aSet.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        rotate();
        break;

    }
}
```

Edit: 
bt1.getX and bt1.getY return 0. Will update once I know why.

Edit: This doesnt seem to work either.

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the size!

    width = bt1.getWidth();
    height = bt1.getHeight();

}
```

Comment: did you figure this out? and, where do you want the pivot point to be? if it's center, I think all you need to do is divide your existing pivot values by two and that should center it

Answer (score 0):

yea `bt1.getWidth()` can't get result but 0 in `onCreate`, because `bt1` was not measured yet.you can have a try follow below:

```
button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout(){
    //here you can get size
    width = button.getWidth();
    height = button.getHeight();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

getX() in OnCreate always give you a zero - it is not "implemented" on view

you have to wait for it. I use this loop to wait for definitely non-zero values:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "checkin... count="+count);
                count++;
            } while (!(playStopButton.getWidth() > 0) && count < 100);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   //here get X, get width etc
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```